# Severe shake from car

Tags: honda, civic, vibration

My car INCONSISTENTLY shakes at various highway speeds. (Between 65 to 80 mph) the shakes feel like they are coming from the front end. When these fits start to happen, my steering wheel also shutters badly. It gets worse when i brake. Again, this problem is inconsistent and when it's not happening, I can brake normally without any shakes.

Heres some more info:
I have a 1997 honda civic ex
The car is automatic
It needs new tires (front end has some life left, back end has lost quite a bit of tread)
I just had my tires balanced
I just got new rotors and breaks put on, Rear brakes have not been changed however

Any info on where to begin looking for the issue? When i took it to my mechanic last week, he couldn't find anything he could think of that would be wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Was this happening before the tire balancing and brakes were done?

Comment: Yes it was. It started the week or so before i got the tires balanced

Comment: I don't understand how the word "inconsistently" is used in the question. Does the car shake only sometimes between 65 and 80 mph, or does it shake always between 65 mph and 80 mph, therefore shaking "inconsistently" overall.

Comment: Hi. It shakes SOMETIMES between 65 and 80 mph

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible things I can think of that you need to get checked :

1) the hub bearings : hub bearings as I had one that was fine around town but the play caused vibration at higher speeds,

2) the suspension joints - because it depends how they were checked - at the "normal" position they can develop a lot of wear, that when moved to another position such as when being jacked up by the subframe can hide a lot of play.